# PyQt QItemDelegate setFocus to QTableWidget after "Enter" is pressed

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, qtablewidget

I am using QTableWidget to creating something like excel. One of the QTableWidget column is able to let user update note with multiple line. Before use QTextEdit, user need to manually add " \n" to achieve multiple line, but this is not friendly user. I found out I can set QTextEdit into QTableWidget. By using QTextEdit, I able to type multiple line by press "Enter" or "Shift+Enter". However, I want when "Shift+Enter" is pressed, it go to next line but when "Enter" is pressed, it run self.update_MySQL function.

Below is my sample code

```
import sys, itertools, sip
sip.setapi('QVariant',2)
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class CustomTextEditDelegate(QtGui.QItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = QtGui.QTextEdit(parent)
        return editor

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        editor.setText(index.data())

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        model.setData(index, editor.toPlainText())

class PIX_DATABASE_UI(QtGui.QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PIX_DATABASE_UI, self).__init__(parent)

        ### signal
        self.update_tableWidget()
        self.itemEntered.connect(self.update_MySQL)

    # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
    def update_MySQL(self):
        print "MySQL Updated"

    def update_tableWidget(self):
        self.filter_columns = [u'remark']
        self.setColumnCount(len(self.filter_columns))
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(self.filter_columns)
        self.setRowCount(5)

        for row, col in itertools.product(range(5), range(len(self.filter_columns))):
            if self.filter_columns[col] == "remark":
                width = self.sizeHint().width()
                self.setColumnWidth(col, width * 0.75)
                self.setItem(row, col, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str("ABC")))
                self.setItemDelegateForColumn(col, CustomTextEditDelegate(self))
                self.verticalHeader().setResizeMode(row, QtGui.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

if __name__ == '__main__':
    global ui
    try:
        ui.close()
    except:
        pass

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle(QtGui.QStyleFactory.create("Plastique"))
    # print QtGui.QStyleFactory.keys()

    ui = PIX_DATABASE_UI()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Conclusion:**

Thanks eyllanesc, the code is help me to achieve what I want to achieve with slightly modify to the keyPressEvent. Original code is still emit even I press "Shift + Enter". 
Below code is what I modified.

```
def keyPressEvent(self, event):
    modifiers = QtGui.QApplication.keyboardModifiers()
    if modifiers != QtCore.Qt.ShiftModifier and event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return:
        self.enter.emit()
        # If you do not want a new line uncomment the following
        # return
    super(TextEdit, self).keyPressEvent(event)
```

So now, after edit in textEdit and press "Enter", it will run self.update_MySQL and when press "Shift + Enter", it will go to next line.

Comment: Why are you using QTextEdit? If you want more lines in a QTextEdit as you would if the task of the enter is just create more lines.

Comment: I am using QTableWidget to creating something like excel. One of the QTableWidget column is able to let user update note with multiple line. Before use QTextEdit, user need to manually  add " \n" to achieve multiple line, but this is not friendly user. And then, I found that I can set QTextEdit into QTableWidget. When using QTextEdit, I able to write multiple line by press "Enter" or "Shift+Enter". However, i just want when "Shift+Enter" is  pressed, it go to next line but when "Enter" is pressed, it run self.update_MySQL function.

Comment: Do not you think it would be the right thing to put that in your question?

Comment: Ok, i will move it my question, thanks for your advise.

Comment: I show my code before asking and you gave me the clarification, so the idea was to filter the SHIFT case as you did :-). I think it's great that you have understood my solution correctly.

Comment: Ya, most of PyQt question in here is answer by you and they are really help me a lot in the road to learning PyQt, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is that the data of the model is updated and for this the `commitData` signal calling the `setModelData()` method must be emited.

By doing this you can use the signal `itemChanged()` because the data of the item is modified.

```
import sys, itertools, sip
sip.setapi('QVariant',2)
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class TextEdit(QtGui.QTextEdit):
    pressed = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return:
            self.pressed.emit()
            # If you do not want a new line uncomment the following
            # return
        super(TextEdit, self).keyPressEvent(event)


class CustomTextEditDelegate(QtGui.QItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = TextEdit(parent)
        editor.pressed.connect(self.commitAndCloseEditor)
        return editor

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        editor.setText(index.data())

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        model.setData(index, editor.toPlainText())

    def commitAndCloseEditor(self):
        editor = self.sender()
        self.commitData.emit(editor)
        # if you want to close the editor uncomment the following
        # self.closeEditor.emit(editor, QtGui.QAbstractItemDelegate.NoHint)

class PIX_DATABASE_UI(QtGui.QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PIX_DATABASE_UI, self).__init__(parent)

        ### signal
        self.update_tableWidget()
        self.itemEntered.connect(self.update_MySQL)
        self.itemChanged.connect(self.update_MySQL)

    # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
    def update_MySQL(self, it):
        print("MySQL Updated", it.text())

    def update_tableWidget(self):
        self.filter_columns = [u'remark']
        self.setColumnCount(len(self.filter_columns))
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(self.filter_columns)
        self.setRowCount(5)

        for row, col in itertools.product(range(5), range(len(self.filter_columns))):
            if self.filter_columns[col] == "remark":
                width = self.sizeHint().width()
                self.setColumnWidth(col, width * 0.75)
                self.setItem(row, col, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str("ABC")))
                self.setItemDelegateForColumn(col, CustomTextEditDelegate(self))
                self.verticalHeader().setResizeMode(row, QtGui.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

if __name__ == '__main__':
    global ui
    try:
        ui.close()
    except:
        pass

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle(QtGui.QStyleFactory.create("Plastique"))
    # print QtGui.QStyleFactory.keys()

    ui = PIX_DATABASE_UI()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Hi eyllanesc, thanks for your reply. Currently my computer is not with me. I will try your code at later morning. I will update here else I test it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you eyllanesc, this is second time your help me, really appreciate for your help again!